# Deserialize JSON using NewtonSoft

Tags: c#, json.net

I have created classes needed by help of a website, but can't deserialize.

```
public class Brand
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}


public class Price
{
    public double current { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Brand brand { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public List<Link> links { get; set; }
    public List<string> mpns { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Price price { get; set; }
    public string productId { get; set; }
}
```

How I am trying in C#

```
string API = "https://www.verkkokauppa.com/resp-api/product?pids=552952"
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(API);
request.Method = "GET";
string result = "";
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
}

var jsonresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);

foreach (Brand p in jsonresult)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(p);
}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, but can anyone help me to correctly get the elements from the classes above only?

Comment: put here result of json data and details of this class `RootObjectVerkkoukappa`.

Comment: Whats the error, and what is the class RootObjectVerkkoukappa? i dont see it in the post

Comment: I checked the json string. Your class(es) doesn't model the json at all.

Comment: Show us the json input - result variable content

Comment: can you debug it  and shows us  an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did it.kindly change your Model. The model should match your JSON data. You can check the complete solution

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace Jsondemo
{
    public class Brand
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string slug { get; set; }
        public string support { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Path
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string slug { get; set; }
        public List<Path> path { get; set; }
    }

    public class Installment
    {
        public int months { get; set; }
        public int monthlySum { get; set; }
        public double totalAmount { get; set; }
        public double annualInterestRate { get; set; }
        public double interest { get; set; }
        public double fee { get; set; }
    }

    public class UiLabels
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
        public string time { get; set; }
        public List<string> tooltip { get; set; }
    }

    public class Installment2
    {
        public int months { get; set; }
        public string monthlySum { get; set; }
        public double totalAmount { get; set; }
        public double annualInterestRate { get; set; }
        public double interest { get; set; }
        public double fee { get; set; }
    }

    public class UiLabels2
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
        public string time { get; set; }
        public List<string> tooltip { get; set; }
    }

    public class CompanyFinancing
    {
        public List<Installment2> installments { get; set; }
        public UiLabels2 uiLabels { get; set; }
    }

    public class Financing
    {
        public List<Installment> installments { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public UiLabels uiLabels { get; set; }
        public CompanyFinancing companyFinancing { get; set; }
    }

    public class Image
    {
        public string __invalid_name__45 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__90 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__300 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__500 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__960 { get; set; }
        public string orig { get; set; }
    }

    public class Link
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Package
    {
        public int width { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
        public int depth { get; set; }
        public int volume { get; set; }
        public int weight { get; set; }
    }

    public class Price
    {
        public double current { get; set; }
        public double currentTaxless { get; set; }
        public string currentFormatted { get; set; }
        public double original { get; set; }
        public double originalTaxless { get; set; }
        public string originalFormatted { get; set; }
        public object discountAmount { get; set; }
        public object discountPercentage { get; set; }
        public int taxRate { get; set; }
        public object discount { get; set; }
        public object deposit { get; set; }
        public object unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rating
    {
        public int reviewCount { get; set; }
        public int averageOverallRating { get; set; }
        public int recommendedCount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Relations
    {
        public List<object> recommended { get; set; }
        public List<object> newer { get; set; }
        public List<object> older { get; set; }
        public List<object> bundles { get; set; }
    }

    public class Restrictions
    {
        public bool isRestricted { get; set; }
        public List<object> pickupAllowed { get; set; }
        public List<object> postalCodeAllowed { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string descriptionShort { get; set; }
    }

    public class ShipmentPrice
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public bool pickup { get; set; }
    }

    public class Js
    {
        public int stock { get; set; }
        public string stockStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pak
    {
        public int stock { get; set; }
        public string stockStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class Vendor
    {
        public int stock { get; set; }
        public string stockStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class Warehouses
    {
        public Js js { get; set; }
        public Pak pak { get; set; }
        public Vendor vendor { get; set; }
    }

    public class Web
    {
        public bool isAvailable { get; set; }
        public bool isPurchasable { get; set; }
        public int stock { get; set; }
        public string stockStatus { get; set; }
        public int minDays { get; set; }
        public int maxDays { get; set; }
        public Warehouses warehouses { get; set; }
        public string ranking { get; set; }
    }

    public class Js2
    {
        public bool isAvailable { get; set; }
        public bool isPurchasable { get; set; }
        public int stock { get; set; }
        public string stockStatus { get; set; }
        public int minDays { get; set; }
        public int maxDays { get; set; }
    }

    public class JsKioski
    {
        public bool isAvailable { get; set; }
        public bool isPurchasable { get; set; }
        public int stock { get; set; }
        public string stockStatus { get; set; }
        public int minDays { get; set; }
        public int maxDays { get; set; }
    }

    public class Oul
    {
        public bool isAvailable { get; set; }
        public bool isPurchasable { get; set; }
        public int stock { get; set; }
        public string stockStatus { get; set; }
        public int minDays { get; set; }
        public int maxDays { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pir
    {
        public bool isAvailable { get; set; }
        public bool isPurchasable { get; set; }
        public int stock { get; set; }
        public string stockStatus { get; set; }
        public int minDays { get; set; }
        public int maxDays { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rai
    {
        public bool isAvailable { get; set; }
        public bool isPurchasable { get; set; }
        public int stock { get; set; }
        public string stockStatus { get; set; }
        public int minDays { get; set; }
        public int maxDays { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pu1
    {
        public bool isAvailable { get; set; }
        public bool isPurchasable { get; set; }
        public int stock { get; set; }
        public string stockStatus { get; set; }
        public int minDays { get; set; }
        public int maxDays { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pu2
    {
        public bool isAvailable { get; set; }
        public bool isPurchasable { get; set; }
        public int stock { get; set; }
        public string stockStatus { get; set; }
        public int minDays { get; set; }
        public int maxDays { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pu3
    {
        public bool isAvailable { get; set; }
        public bool isPurchasable { get; set; }
        public int stock { get; set; }
        public string stockStatus { get; set; }
        public int minDays { get; set; }
        public int maxDays { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pu4
    {
        public bool isAvailable { get; set; }
        public bool isPurchasable { get; set; }
        public int stock { get; set; }
        public string stockStatus { get; set; }
        public int minDays { get; set; }
        public int maxDays { get; set; }
    }

    public class Stores
    {
        public Js2 js { get; set; }
        public JsKioski js_kioski { get; set; }
        public Oul oul { get; set; }
        public Pir pir { get; set; }
        public Rai rai { get; set; }
        public Pu1 pu1 { get; set; }
        public Pu2 pu2 { get; set; }
        public Pu3 pu3 { get; set; }
        public Pu4 pu4 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Stocks
    {
        public Web web { get; set; }
        public Stores stores { get; set; }
    }

    public class Availability
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public int pid { get; set; }
        public object overrideText { get; set; }
        public bool isElectronic { get; set; }
        public bool isVirtual { get; set; }
        public bool isInStoresOnly { get; set; }
        public bool isReleased { get; set; }
        public bool isShippingAllowed { get; set; }
        public bool isPickupAllowed { get; set; }
        public bool isStockVisible { get; set; }
        public bool isPurchasable { get; set; }
        public bool isSoldOut { get; set; }
        public bool isEOL { get; set; }
        public bool isFastDeliveryAvailable { get; set; }
        public bool isStoreOrderAllowed { get; set; }
        public bool hasStock { get; set; }
        public Stocks stocks { get; set; }
        public List<object> tags { get; set; }
        public DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime verifiedAt { get; set; }
        public int updateCount { get; set; }
        public DateTime updateStartTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }
        public int ageLimit { get; set; }
        public Brand brand { get; set; }
        public List<string> bulletPoints { get; set; }
        public List<object> bundleProducts { get; set; }
        public List<object> campaigns { get; set; }
        public List<string> categories { get; set; }
        public Category category { get; set; }
        public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
        public List<object> demoLocations { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string descriptionShort { get; set; }
        public List<string> eans { get; set; }
        public bool electronic { get; set; }
        public Financing financing { get; set; }
        public string freeShipmentFor { get; set; }
        public bool hidePriceEstimate { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
        public List<Image> images { get; set; }
        public List<Link> links { get; set; }
        public object maxAmountPerOrder { get; set; }
        public List<string> mpns { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Package package { get; set; }
        public int pid { get; set; }
        public Price price { get; set; }
        public string productId { get; set; }
        public Rating rating { get; set; }
        public Relations relations { get; set; }
        public DateTime releasedAt { get; set; }
        public Restrictions restrictions { get; set; }
        public List<string> ribbons { get; set; }
        public List<ShipmentPrice> shipmentPrices { get; set; }
        public List<object> shopAreas { get; set; }
        public bool vak { get; set; }
        public int visible { get; set; }
        public string warranty { get; set; }
        public DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime verifiedAt { get; set; }
        public int updateCount { get; set; }
        public DateTime updateStartTime { get; set; }
        public Availability availability { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string API = "https://www.verkkokauppa.com/resp-api/product?pids=552952";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(API);
            request.Method = "GET";
            string result = "";
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
            }

            var jsonresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(result);

           foreach (RootObject p in jsonresult)
        {
            foreach (var item in p.links)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(item.href);
            }

        }
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! But how do I get value from these classes `    public List<Link> links { get; set; }
    public List<string> mpns { get; set; }`

Comment: You have to use foreach and iterate it

Comment: `foreach (RootObject p in jsonresult)
            {
Console.WriteLine(p.links);
                Console.WriteLine(p.mpns);
            }` They both gives error.

Comment: Not this way..you have use foreach in foreach loop coz links and mpns are lists

Comment: Can you show me in code. I can't able to solve this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193914/discussion-between-sunil-dhappadhule-and-aap).

Answer (score 2):

There are few mistakes in the code you've provided:

1. The json which is received from endpoint, is a json array.
   So, instead of deserialzing as `RootObject` you should deserialize as `List<RootObject>`.
2. While iterating through `jsonresult` you should use `RootObject` instead of `Brand`

So here is the complete solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Brand
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Price
{
    public double current { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Brand brand { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public List<Link> links { get; set; }
    public List<string> mpns { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Price price { get; set; }
    public string productId { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string API = "https://www.verkkokauppa.com/resp-api/product?pids=552952";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(API);
        request.Method = "GET";
        string result = "";
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
        }

        var jsonresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(result);

        foreach (RootObject p in jsonresult)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(p.brand.name);

            foreach (Link link in p.links){
                Debug.WriteLine(link.href);
            }
            foreach (string mpn in p.mpns){
                Debug.WriteLine(mpn);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jpz8wK) is the online version just in case it's needed.

Comment: Great! But I can't get values for mpns and links.href :  `public List<Link> links { get; set; }  
    public List<string> mpns { get; set; }`

Comment: @AAP That's because they both are lists :) so you should use something like this instead: "p.links[0].href" "p.mpns[0]" or iterate over lists instead. I've updated the answer. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://quicktype.io to generate c# code with entities from JSON.

i have created the c# classes for your json request.

https://app.quicktype.io?share=KNyJfG7rGBZH96H6yNXe

Comment: Thanks for answer but the classes are too long to be understood for me. Can you help me to get only the desired element from classes above in my question.  Also reading values and get output like Debug.Writeline(brand.name) like this using foreach loop or something. I am not very experienced.